# Cannot upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Have a new Asus laptop and wanted to go from 8 to 8.1.  Downloaded the upgrade in the form of a disc image, but when required to enter the product Key it is rejected.  It is a new computer with pre-installed software.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a version conflict. From which version to which version do you upgrade? pro to pro?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the problem is, you have a new Asus laptop with Windows 8 on it and you are trying to install Windows 8.1 onto it from a disc image?

The product key you are entering is probably for Windows 8 OEM only (a product key for the pre-installed software) and not one for a "full" version of Windows 8 / 8.1.

The solution is to wait until Windows 8.1 is available for free and download and install this on your Windows 8 machine.

Comment: This is simply not right...

Comment: @Richard - This is the best solution given that in 5 days the problem the author faces won't be a problem.

Comment: Could you explain simply what is not right about it @TheX ?

Comment: @ThaX - This is indeed correct. A Windows 8.0 license cannot be used to install Windows 8.1. A generic Windows 8.1 key is required to upgrade to Windows 8.1 if a Windows 8.1 installation media is used to do the upgrade. This requires changing the license key after installation. Waiting for the Windows Store method is the best solution for people without the technical skills to use the traditional installation media method.

Comment: Okay fine I am going to go back into my corner and cry now :-P

Comment: You've probably downloaded the Enterprise version and tried to upgrade the OEM version.If you can download Windows 8.1 OEM update, your product key should be OK. I have upgraded from Windows 8 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise without any issues. Upgrade to Windows 8.1 is free for all Windows 8 users and therefore all licence keys for Windows 8 are valid for Windows 8.1 upgrade. Upgrade will be available via Windows update